# html form: input requierd if Select>optinon selected

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to make a field **mandatory** if the option of a select is selected.

Here's the code to be clear :) :

```
<div class="value">
   <h2>Are you happy ?</h2>
   <select name="happiness" required>
        <option value="1">Good</option>
        <option value="0">To improve</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   <textarea name="Comment4Happiness" placeholder="comment"></textarea>
</div>
```

So the textarea have to be **mandatory** if the option "**To improve**" is selected.
We can also fill the `text area` with a comment if we want. But that's not mandatory!

I already know that I have to use Javascript, but I do not know this domain...

Comment: Before to get help here we used to ask you to try something. Then you may have some help from one of us. I invite you to read this guide "[ask]" to improve your chance to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press on submit button and you will see mandatory for select option **To improve.**

```js
function checkHappiness(happiness) {
  if(happiness.value === "0") {
    document.getElementById("comment").required = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("comment").required = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="value">
<form action="/action_page.php">
   <h2>Are you happy now ?</h2>
   <select name="happiness" onchange="checkHappiness(this)" required>
        <option value="1">Good</option>
        <option value="0" selected>To improve</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   <textarea name="Comment4Happiness" value="value1" placeholder="comment" id="comment" ></textarea>
  <input type="submit">   
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add id's to your form elements and then use them in your JavaScript to get their value and a submit button to call the function.

```
<div class="value">
   <h2>Are you happy ?</h2>
   <select id="mySelect" name="happiness" required>
        <option value="1">Good</option>
        <option value="0">To improve</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   <textarea id="myTextArea" name="Comment4Happiness" placeholder="comment"></textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Now add a script tag to the bottom of your html

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
  let selectValue = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  let textAreaValue = document.getElementById("myTextArea").value;
   if (selectValue === "0") {
    if (textAreaValue === "") {
      alert("Text Area should not be empty");
    }

   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

I added a id to the `textarea`. and added a function when the select box onChange.

```js
function checkHappiness(happiness) {
  if(happiness.value === "0") {
    document.getElementById("comment").required = true;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("comment").required = false;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="value">
   <h2>Are you happy ?</h2>
   <select name="happiness" onchange="checkHappiness(this)" required>
        <option value="1">Good</option>
        <option value="0">To improve</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   <textarea name="Comment4Happiness" placeholder="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
</div>
```